# Ajax error not loading message

Tags: java, javascript, jquery, ajax, servlets

I am receiving an error not loading message when I click on my submit button on my login.html. I don't have much experience with this and there are no error messages to point me in the direction to fix it. 
I have my login.html

```
<body>
    <div id="log">
    <h2>Login</h2>
    <form method="post" action="login" class="form-1" accept-charset="utf-8" onsubmit="sendAjax()">
        <input type="text" name="username" id="username" placeholder="Username"/><br/>
        <input type="password" name="password" id="password" placeholder="Password"/><br/>
        <input type="submit" value="Sign In"/>
    </form>
    </div>
</body>
```

which is called into a div in my index.html

```
$('#login').click(function(e){ 
$('#map-canvas').addClass("hidden");
$('#dMain').removeClass("hidden");
$('#dMain').load('html/login.html');
e.preventDefault();
```

my login servlet

```
    response.setContentType("text/html;charset=UTF-8");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    String username = request.getParameter("username");
    String password = request.getParameter("password");

    if(databaseConnection.checkUser(username, password))
    {
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("Welcome");
        rs.forward(request, response);
    }
    else
    {
        out.println("Username or Password incorrect");
        RequestDispatcher rs = request.getRequestDispatcher("login.html");
        rs.include(request, response);
    }
}
```

and my ajax function

```
function sendAjax(){
    var article = new Object();
    article.username = $('#username').val();
    article.password = $('#password').val();

    $ajax({
        url: "http://localhost:8080/FishingTrax/LoginServlet",
        type: 'POST',
        dataType: 'json',
        data: JSON.stringify(article),
        contentType: 'application/json',
        mimeType: 'application/json',

        success: function (data) {

        },
            error:function(data,status,er) {
                alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
                }
    });
};
```

Comment: `onsubmit="return sendAjax()"`(or add the event handler in the head as prescribed)  and in sendAjax add a `return false;` to the end. Also you assign something to a `$('#login')`which does not exist

Comment: I added changed the onsubmit to have the return sendAjax() and added return false into the ajax.  the login is a button from my menu that loads the login.html into a div on my index.html page.
Sadly I am still receiving the error loading page problem, but I am loading the script on my index page as I know that can be missed when loading into a div on another html page.

Comment: okay, so I am getting the error not loading and Reference error: sendAjax is not defined in index.html

Answer (score 0):

I had two problems with my code, I was lacking the return prior to the sendAjax(). The define Ajax problem was due to missing a full stop in $ajax so it should be $.ajax

```
function sendAjax(){
var article = new Object();
article.username = $('#username').val();
article.password = $('#password').val();

$.ajax({
    url: "http://localhost:8080/FishingTrax/LoginServlet",
    type: 'POST',
    dataType: 'json',
    data: JSON.stringify(article),
    contentType: 'application/json',
    mimeType: 'application/json',

    success: function (data) {

    },
        error:function(data,status,er) {
            alert("error: "+data+" status: "+status+" er:"+er);
            }
});
```

};